# Can't insert a row via SqlAdapter

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the following code to insert a new row to an existing Database table:

```
     string strSQL2= "SELECT * FROM Staff";
     SqlAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL2, conString);
     Dataset ds = new DataSet();
     dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
     DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
     newRow["firstName"] = "Michael";
     newRow["lastName"] = "Jackson";
     newRow["username"] = "Michi";
     newRow["admin"] = "0";
     ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);
     var cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
     dataAdapter.Update(ds);
```

The code is meant to update the original database but it doesn't. I don't get any error. In SQL profiler I don't see any command received. What could be the problem?

Comment: Why are you using a SqlAdapter instead of SqlCommand with an UPDATE statement? Adapters are used to load/save DataTables, *not* to execute SQL commands

Comment: I don't agree @PanagiotisKanavos. DataAdapters are also meant to do updates, deletes...

Comment: @Pikoh for DataTable data only. Why go through a DataTable when you can execute the command you want directly?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos of course I won't use a nonsense DataAdapter just to insert a row. But, lets say you load a DataTable to feed a DataGridView. You can use that DataAdapter to insert new records, update them, delete...etc. I use it very often

Comment: @Pikoh Fine, but if you look at the question, that doesn't appear to be what's going on here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using a Data Table in order to use Database resources efficiently, the software is much larger than my given example. I have to simplify things here a bit so that you could understand it easier.

Comment: @mason well,this is a code sample. But anyway, what is was disagreing with was this: _Adapters are used to load/save DataTables_

Answer (score 1):

Why don´t you try more conventional?:

```
private void InsertStaff()
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO Staff (firstname, lastname, username, admin) VALUES (@firstname, @lastname, @username, 0)";

    SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[3];
    parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@firstname", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = @firstname;
    parameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@lastname", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = @lastname;
    parameters[2] = new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = @username;

    ExecuteNonQuery(query, parameters);
}


private void ExecuteNonQuery(string query, SqlParameter[] parametros)
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Server + ";Initial Catalog=" + Database + ";User Id=" + Username + ";Password=" + Password + ";");
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = query;

        foreach (SqlParameter p in parametros)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(p);
        }

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, give me a moment, I'll try it out.

Comment: @Dovile be sure to replace all connectionstring settings

Comment: I've looked the code through. I'm sure it works, but it's more of a workaround. My company wants me to use a Dataset. The goal is to fill a dataset with original information from the Database, update it with new information (in this case, inserting a new row) and in the end, synchronize the Database with the Dataset. Thanks very much anyway.

Comment: @Dovile I do not see the advantage of that

Comment: Do not catch an exception just to throw it again. Your code would be cleaner if you used `using` statements to wrap your IDisposables instead, it would prevent you from using them out of scope and eliminate the explicit closeing and disposing.

Comment: @mason I do know that. The code is more a guidance for OP than a real production one. Thanks by the way for the pointer. 'Using' is always better but for this case having explicitely written shows OP that the object HAS to be disposed and closed.

Comment: @NicoRiff the advantage lies within the fact that you don't have to burden your network with constant connections, disconnections, queries and commands. If you use a dataset you can collect all the commands that need to be executed over a longer period of time and execute them at one single go.

Comment: @Dovile That should not be a problem nowadays. You can use connection pool to reduce handshake communications. You have ways to work that out. What kind of application are we talking?. Your worries are about bandwidth usage?. I assume your app is not real time.

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow stick around for a long time - you should not promote bad practices like catching an exception just to rethrow it. And what do you think a `using` statement does? Closes and disposes. There really isn't a good reason not to use it here.